# Is it possible to recreate iPhone pro frosted glass material using Blender's standard shader nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, shaders

Apple "Pro" iPhone models have had a frosted glass back material for a while now and I am not quite sure how to incorporate such a material in my models using Blender's standard shader editor.

Here are some examples of what I am going for. The first image is a render by Ian Zelbo and the second is what the material looks like in reality.

[image: https://zelbo.nyc/portfolio-item/iphone14pro-a/]

[image: https://www.notebookcheck.net/Apple-iPhone-13-Pro-Review-Bombastic-smartphone-with-minor-weaknesses.572211.0.html]

Here is what I have so far, rendered with Cycles.

[image]

I think my biggest issue is adding color while also retaining the physical characteristics of a frosted glass material. I have attached a link to the blend file containing the glass back object with the material.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O7T4xhfaqiB6F_nzUSR_Qf8ICPtoigj7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2):

In short, almost anything you can think of is possible with blender these days. For something like this, the easiest way to achieve this kind of look is to use a Principled BSDF Shader with specific parameters. Keep in mind, with almost all reflective surfaces such as glass, the realistic effect they give is highly dependent on the lighting and environment the object is in because of reflections. I would highly suggest using an HDRI environment texture with something like this.

To get a pretty close material to what is seen on the iPhone Pro Models I got this Principled BSDF setup:
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, just by rotating around the object the reflections and material look completely different so just be careful about that. You might also want to think about adding surface imperfections such as fingerprints and scratches if you are going for realism.